# Программа поиска и замены на Python или С++

Tags: c++, python, случайные-числа

Нужно написать программу, работающую по типу Поиска и Замены в Ворде. Но при этом замена должна происходить на случайно-сгенерированное слово из набора букв. 
То есть, у нас есть, например, следующий текст: `"Дима, как у тебя дела? Надеюсь, что хорошо"`

Программа должна менять все запятые в тексте на случайно-сгенерированное слово из букв `(а, б, е, г, р, о)`.

Разумеется, символы для замены и набор букв, из которых будет происходить генерация могут быть любыми.

На данный момент есть следующий код на Python:

```
import random
str4 = ("аобевисом")
ls = list(str4)
z = [('. ',''.join([random.choice(ls) for x in range(5)]))]
s = input("Введите текст для замены")
for p in z: s=s.replace(p[0],p[1])
print (s)
```

Код частично справляется, в данном случае меняет точки с пробелом, но имеет критические недоработки

1. Отсутствие разделителей после замены
   То есть, если мы вводим с клавиатуры для проверки, например: "пирожок. пончик"
   Он заменяет вот так: пирожок*рандом-слово из букв*пончик
   А нужно так: пирожок, *рандом-слово из букв*, пончик
2. Одно и тоже слово на всю замену
   То есть, программа формирует случайное слово из выбранного набора букв, и далее меняет все точки с пробелом, на это слово, а нужно, чтобы точки с пробелом заменялись на новое сгенерированное слово.
   Постарался описать максимально понятно, думаю, программисты поймут:)

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такое решение устроит?

```
import re
import random
import itertools

searchstr=r', '
heap = ('а', 'б', 'е', 'г', 'р', 'о')
text = "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod, tempor incididunt, ut labore,"

def gen_word(heap):
    return ''.join(random.choice(list(itertools.permutations(heap))))

def callback(matchobj):
    return ", "+gen_word(heap)+", "

res = re.sub(searchstr, callback, text)
print(res)
```

Вот вариант результата:

> Lorem ipsum, героаб, dolor sit amet, огрбае, consectetur, арегоб, adipiscing elit, баеогр, sed do eiusmod, рабгео, tempor incididunt, бегора, ut labore,